# The asymptotic behavior of the iteration series $x_{n+1} = x_n - x_n^2 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Let the initial value $x_0 \in (0, 1/2)$.

What is the asymptotic behavior of the converging series $\{x_n\} $?

I have tried the ansatz that

$$x_n \simeq  \frac{1}{n} + \frac{a_2}{n^2} + \frac{a_3}{n^3} + \ldots $$

The finding is that $a_2$ can be arbitrary, while there is no consistent value for $a_3$. This indicates that the ansatz is wrong.

Comment: Have you plotted it?

Comment: Sure. It converges to zero. But that is trivial.

Comment: Mind including your work so that we may see why you think $a_2$ should be arbitrary?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506723/find-asymptotic-of-recurrence-sequence, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558592/convergence-rate-of-the-sequence-a-n1-a-n-a-n2-a-0-1-2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recursion you are interested in can be rewritten as $$\frac1{x_{n+1}}-\frac1{x_n}=\frac1{1-x_n}\tag{$\ast$}$$ You said you already know that $x_n=o(1)$, hence $(\ast)$ yields $$\frac1{x_{n+1}}-\frac1{x_n}=1+o(1)$$ which shows that $$\frac1{x_n}=n+o(n)$$ hence $$x_n=\frac1n+o\left(\frac1n\right)$$ Using this and plugging it back into the RHS of $(\ast)$ yields $$\frac1{x_{n+1}}-\frac1{x_n}=\frac1{1-\frac1n+o\left(\frac1n\right)}=1+\frac1n+o\left(\frac1n\right)$$
which shows that $$\frac1{x_n}=n+\log n+o(\log n)$$ or, equivalently,
$$x_n=\frac1n-\frac{\log n}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{\log n}{n^2}\right)$$
This expansion explains why trying to expand $x_n$ into powers of $\frac1n$ fails.

Note finally that one can again plug this last expansion above back into $(\ast)$ above to compute the next terms of the expansion of $\frac1{x_n}$, and consequently of $x_n$.

Comment: (+1) Very clearly and concisely explained!  Well done.  Is there not a constant term in the asymptotic expansion?

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks. Where do you think a term is lacking?

Answer (score 5):

Let $y_n=1/x_n$. Then
$$y_{n+1}=\frac{y_n}{1-1/y_n}=y_n\left(1+\frac1{y_n}+\frac1{y_n^2}+\cdots\right)=y_n+1+O(1/y_n).$$
Therefore $y_n\ge n-A$ for some fixed $A$. Putting this in the above gives
$y_n=n+O(\ln n)$. This gives
$$x_n=\frac1n+O\left(\frac{\ln n}{n^2}\right).$$
One can go further....