# Reference stability/convergence of nonlinear recurrence relations using analytical methods

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, recurrence-relations

### Example of a problem

Let’s say we have the recurrence relation :
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{2}{3}(2x_n -x_n^2).
$$
We can easily find its fixed points, namely $x=0$ and $x=1/2$. I have found numerically that for $x_0 \in (0,1)$ we have $x_n \rightarrow 1/2$. I would like to prove that this is indeed the case using generally applicable methods.

### General Question

I have read about Jacobians etc. to be used to study the stability of fixed points and to show that a sequence indeed converges to (or does not converge to) a given fixed point. However, I do not seem to find a decent reference on the internet where this theory is discussed in detail.

Comment: The [MSE question 2900474](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900474/) "Asymptotic expansion of $a_1=1, a_n=a_{n-1}-a_{n-1}^2/2$" will get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\in(0,1/2)$ we have

$$0<x<\frac{4x-2x^2}3<\frac12$$

and for $x\in(1/2,1)$ we have

$$\frac12<\frac{4x-2x^2}3<x<1$$

which proves this is monotone and bounded, and hence convergent. We can then easily see that it converges to $1/2$ because we find equality in this interval only when $x=1/2$.