# How do I show the limit of this iterative equation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, numerical-optimization

I have an iterative equation defined by $\theta_k$
$$
2\theta_{k+1} = -\theta_k^2 + \sqrt{ \theta_k^4 + 4\theta_k^2}
$$
and $\theta_0 = 1$.

How do I show that then $\theta_k(\theta_{k-1}^{-1} - 1)$ asymptotically equals $1-3/k + O(1/k^2)$

I know $\theta_k$ tends to zero and so $\theta_k(\theta_{k-1}^{-1} - 1)$ which is

$$
\dfrac{\sqrt{ \theta_k^2 + 4} - \theta_k}{2} - \dfrac{-\theta_k^2 + \sqrt{ \theta_k^4 + 4\theta_k^2}}{2}
$$

tends to 1.

Then I'm not too sure how to calculate the $\dfrac{1}{k}$ coefficient. It seems those similar questions are well studied so have clever tricks that work but not sure it translates to this case easily.

Comment: Please read similar [MSE question 2900474](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2900474) "Asymptotic expansion of $a_1=1,a_n=a_{n-1}-a_{n-1}^2/2$"

Comment: Oh yeah you're right! that looks very similar to what I want! thanks

Comment: @Somos I'm still stuck on this question I'll add my working